# Something has seriously gone wrong with my windows 8.1 PC

Tags: windows-8.1, symbols

I just switched on my computer, running Windows 8.1 and all of these weird symbols have replaced the names of my items on the desktop and apps!!

[image: some icons]

[image: the run menu]

Can someone help me on this? I'm really scared right now

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why this is happening, I'll switch to my win7 is

Comment: @Mrfunny744 - You don't need to switch.  Just fix your problem.